# Dart execute command always `No such file or directory`

Tags: dart

I want to execute a command `python /Users/xx/mail_utils.py` in Dart. As you see,  I have used absolute python file path.

When I execute above command in terminal, it works. However when I call it in Dart.

```
Process.run('python /Users/xx/mail_utils.py',['xx']).then((ProcessResult results) {
  print(results.stdout);
});
```

> Unhandled exception:
>
> ProcessException: No such file or directory
>
> Command: python /Users/xx/mail_utils.py xx

What's wrong ?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You probably want

```
Process.run('python', ['/Users/xx/mail_utils.py','xx']).then((ProcessResult results) {
  print(results.stdout);
});
```

The first parameter should only be the executable. Parameters go into the array that is passed as second parameter.